# Change text in a QAction that's inside of a QMenu

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenu objects to which I've added several QAction objects with a certain text. All works well, except that I would like to change the text of those QActions at runtime. I've looked at the QMenu API and didn't find any way to to get them. I also tried actions.at(x) and a few other things. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you are structuring your app. In some circumstances you might be saving your `QAction`'s as members, to which you could access directly. Or you might just be saving the `QMenu` and populating it with `QAction`'s. Either way, once you have your action, you just call `setText(QString)` on it:

```
// init
menu = new QMenu(this);
...
menu->addAction("foo");

// later on
QAction *action = menu->actions().at(0); // access just the first QAction
action->setText("bar");
```

`QMenu` also allows you to look up actions by a `QPoint` location. Again, it really depends on exactly how you will be determining which action you want to change.

Comment: Thanks. I just had a pointer to the QAction I was adding and then modified it.